# xcode - mac - detect window (focus) change

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there a way to detect window change in macOS even with same App? Right now im doing this:

```
NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onAppFocusChange), name: .NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplication, object: nil)
```

It works with different apps (if you change focus from Chrome to Safari), but it's not working with same app.

Comment: I’m interested in this too